# How to deserialize list to take element value

Tags: c#, .net, xml, list, serialization

I try to test 1 HTTP POST XML request to my web API, with the XML like this:

```
<trx>
            <header>...</header>
            <body>
        <unity keycnt="4">
            <key param="param1"><![CDATA[value1]]</key>
            <key param="param2"><![CDATA[value2]]</key>
            <key param="param3"><![CDATA[value3]]</key>
            <key param="param4"><![CDATA[value4]]</key>
            </unity>
        </body>
        </trx>
```

When I deserialize that request with a list  of class like this:

```
 [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="trx")]
    public class Trx {
        [XmlElement("header")]
        public Header Header { get; set;}
         [XmlElement("body")]
        public Body Body{ get; set;}
    }
```

class Body:

```
 [Serializable()]
    public class Body{
        [XmlElement("unity")]
        public Unity Unity{ get; set;}
    }
```

class Unity:

```
  [Serializable()]
        public class Unity{
            [XmlAttribute("keycnt")]
            public string keycnt{ get; set;}
       [XmlElement("key")]
            public List<Key> KeyList{ get; set;}
        }
```

class Key:

```
  [Serializable()]
            public class Key{
                [XmlAttribute("param")]
                public string param{ get; set;}
            }
```

After deserializing, I get all the attributes except the value of key list items.(value1, value2, value3, value4 )

Comment: could you please show your code for deserialization of xml?

Comment: Have a look at https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Hi @HirenND, I'm seeing that you have marked unanswered to my solution, Is there any reason? do you need more help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add one more property to your `Key` class with `string` datatype and then your `XmlSerializer` will give you deserialize your values inside `CDATA`.

And decorate this property with `[XmlText]`. This attribute can gives you CDATA as text in particular node in xml.

So your `Key` class should be.

```
[Serializable()]
public class Key
{
    [XmlAttribute("param")]
    public string param { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check you input XML as well. Your XML is malformed. Here is corrected one. CDATA element was missing > at the end.

```
<trx>
<header></header>
<body>
    <unity keycnt="4">
        <key param="param1"><![CDATA[value1]]></key>
        <key param="param2"><![CDATA[value2]]></key>
        <key param="param3"><![CDATA[value3]]></key>
        <key param="param4"><![CDATA[value4]]></key>
    </unity>
</body>
```

Comment: sorry, it's typo :D